# Android : Connection refused at POP3Store

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

Below is my code for connecting POP3 using SSL.

```
public void pop3 ()throws Exception{

    // connect to my pop3 inbox
    String a = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.host" , "myhost");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port" , "myport");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.user" , "username");
    // Start SSL connection
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory" , "myport");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class" , a );



    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    try {

        Store emailStore = session.getStore("pop3s");
        
        // getting error while connecting 

        emailStore.connect("myhost",port,"username", "password");

        Folder inbox = emailStore.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // get the list of inbox messages
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

        if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            // stop after listing ten messages
            if (i > 10) {
                System.exit(0);
                inbox.close(true);
                emailStore.close();
            }

            Log.e("Message " , String.valueOf((i + 1)));
            Log.e("From : " , String.valueOf(messages[i].getFrom()[0]));
            Log.e("Subject : " ,messages[i].getSubject());
            Log.e("Sent Date : " , String.valueOf(messages[i].getSentDate()));

        }

        inbox.close(true);
        emailStore.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everytime I am getting the following error:

> W/System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
>
> W/System.err:   nested exception is:
>
> W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
> W/System.err: at
>
> com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:161)
>
> .....

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "myhost" isn't listening on "myport".

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the socket factory stuff, [you don't need it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

You're setting properties for the "pop3" protocol, but you're using the "pop3s" protocol.  It's simpler to just use the "pop3" protocol and set the `mail.pop3.ssl.enable` property to `true`.